# not able to add more that 6 products to cart in codeigniter application

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, jquery-mobile

As I am not able to add more than 6 products to the cart in codeigniter.

What can be the issue?
As while I am adding 7th product, cart gets updated for a while. then after refreshing the page, it again displaying 6 products only.

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/146771/#901602

Comment: Code you've tried? Errors? It's hard to guess what's going on, maybe the item is out of stock?

Comment: yes. thanks for replying. As I found the issue is because of cookie size. Now my question is how to increase the limit of cookie size.? is it possible? if yes, then how? please help.

Comment: @user985361 Don't think you can increase the limit. It's browser dependent and most have 4Kb as limit. I have put an answer below that may help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is probably that you exceeded cookie size limit. Most browsers max size is around 4Kb.

What can solve your problem is to store it in database instead of cookie:

Set `$config[‘sess_use_database’]` to `true` in your **config.php**

Comment: Works for me too, thanks! Don't forget to create the ci_sessions table (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 4):

@Nathan Q : You are right. Its solved my issue. Moreover, find below the script for ci_session table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```